# Ubicación de tablas de mantenimiento

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Solicito la ayuda de los expertos. Tengo un sistema que utiliza varios módulos cada uno con sus tablas de mantenimiento propias.
Mi pregunta: ¿Debo colocar todas las tablas de mantenimiento en un solo módulo (Administración del Sistema, por ejemplo)? ¿O dejo cada tabla de mantenimiento en su módulo correspondiente y en el módulo Administración del Sistema coloco las tablas obvias como usuarios, perfiles, roles etc. junto a las tablas de mantenimiento que son usadas por todo el sistema?

Comment: Lo correcto seria realizar un modulo de mantenimientos, donde se encuentren todos los mantenimientos del sistema como tu mismo lo indicas con el nombre **Administracion del sistema**, de esta manera el usuario aprendera que si tiene que realizar un mantenimiento debe dirigirse alli y no acada uno de los modulos de los cuales el quiere realizar la madoficacion. De esta manera el usuario sabra que cuando quiere realizar un mantenimiento debe dirigirse **Administracion de sistema** directamente.